# What kinds of cells does human saliva contain?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology

I have heard that our saliva contains cells. What cell types can be found in human saliva?

Comment: I clarified the question and vote for reopening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It contains white blood cells (*leukocytes*) and cells from the inner lining of the mouth (*buccal epithelial cells*). The DNA obtained from these cells is the basis of DNA profiling based on saliva samples.

Source: [Salimetrics](http://www.salimetrics.com/article/collecting-and-handling-saliva-for-dna-analysis)